# Azure - Subscription Quota

Tags: azure

Each azure subscription has some predefined resource like cpu(20)/host services(6) storage(5) etc..

I was wondering if there is a way using the azure sdk api to get that information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quotas cannot be programmatically returned today.  At this point, it is a 'business' concept, not a technical one.  So, while the Service Management API can tell you about your running instances and storage accounts, it cannot tell you about any quota.  Note, that is the scenario today.  I would imagine over time this would change as it would be nice to know without logging into MOCP (the Billing Portal).